# structure vector push_back C++

Tags: c++, vector, struct, push-back

I'm having a problem figuring out how to use push_back function to push array elements of a structure into the TeamV vector.

Here is the code i have so far:

```
const int MEMBERS = 3;
const int TEAM_NUM = 4;

struct TeamS
{
   int ID_NUM;
   string team_members;
};


int main()
{
   int arrayS = 0;
   const int ID[TEAM_NUM] = { 123, 321, 456, 789 };
   const string TEAM [TEAM_NUM][MEMBERS] =
   {
      { "Sarah", "Joe", "John" }, 
      { "Chris", "Kevin", "James" }, 
      { "Tom", "Kim", "Emily" }, 
      { "Jill", "Jason", "Jim" }
   };
   vector <TeamS> TeamV;
   Initialize(TeamV, ID, TEAM, arrayS);

   return 0;
}



void Initialize(vector <TeamS> & TeamV, const int Id[], const string m[][MEMBERS], int arraysize)
{
   cout << "Starting initialization" << endl;
   for (arraysize; arraysize < TEAM_NUM; arraysize++)
   {
      TeamV.push_back(???)
         TeamV [arraysize].ID_NUM = Id[arraysize];
      TeamV [arraysize].team_members = m[arraysize][MEMBERS];

   }
   cout << "Ending initialization" << endl;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're *sure* you don't want `TeamS:: team_members ` to be a `std::vector<std::string>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, you need to change `TeamS` to have a list of `string`s for team members, not just one `string`.

  ```
  struct TeamS
  {
     int ID_NUM;
     std::vector<string> team_members;
  };
  ```
- In the function to initialize `teamV`:

  ```
  void Initialize(vector <TeamS> & TeamV, const int Id[], const string m[][MEMBERS], int arraysize)
  {
     cout << "Starting initialization" << endl;
     for (arraysize; arraysize < TEAM_NUM; arraysize++)
     {
        // Create an instance of TeamS and flesh out its contents.
        TeamS team;
        team.ID_NUM = Id[arraysize];
        for ( int i = 0; i < MEMBERS; ++i )
        {
           team.team_members.push_back(m[arraysize][i]);
        }

        // Now add the TeamS to TeamV.
        TeamV.push_back(team);
     }
     cout << "Ending initialization" << endl;
  }
  ```

  You can take a slightly different approach where you add an empty `TeamS` to `TeamV` and flesh out the contents of the member already in `TeamV`.

  ```
  void Initialize(vector <TeamS> & TeamV, const int Id[], const string m[][MEMBERS], int arraysize)
  {
     cout << "Starting initialization" << endl;
     for (arraysize; arraysize < TEAM_NUM; arraysize++)
     {
        // Add an tempy TeamS to TeamV.
        TeamS team;
        TeamV.push_back(team);

        // Flesh out its contents of the element in TeamV.
        TeamV[arraysize].ID_NUM = Id[arraysize];
        for ( int i = 0; i < MEMBERS; ++i )
        {
           TeamV[arraysize].team_members.push_back(m[arraysize][i]);
        }
     }
     cout << "Ending initialization" << endl;
  }
  ```